# searching for an item in an array triggered by tap gesture handler

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have the following code with the attempt to have a scrollView with letters. In viewDidLoad I create and add the images to the scrollView and to an array - imgs[UIImageView]. When I check the imgs array for the index of a certain item it returns an optional value on the first print (in the viewDidLoad method), however I added the tapGestureRecognizer hoping to be able to find the image in the array once its tapped, but when I print the imgs.getIndexOf in the tapGesture handler I get nil (the array count is correct). Any ideas on how to resolve?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {    

    @IBOutlet weak var myScrollView: UIScrollView!
    private let lettersModel:LettersModel = LettersModel();
    private var imgs = [UIImageView]();
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(myScrollView)


        var yPosition:CGFloat = 0
        var scrollViewContentSize:CGFloat=0;
        let imageWidth:CGFloat = myScrollView.frame.width
        let imageHeight:CGFloat = myScrollView.frame.width
        let spacer:CGFloat = 20
        for var index=0; index<lettersModel.letters.count; index++
        {

            let myImage:UIImage = UIImage(named: lettersModel.getLetterAt(index))!
            let myImageView:UIImageView = UIImageView()
            myImageView.image = myImage
            myImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit

            myImageView.frame.size.width = imageWidth
            myImageView.frame.size.height = imageHeight
            myImageView.frame.origin.y = yPosition

            myScrollView.addSubview(myImageView)



            yPosition+=imageHeight + spacer
            scrollViewContentSize+=imageHeight + spacer
            myScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: imageWidth, height: scrollViewContentSize)
            imgs.append(myImageView)


            print("viewDidLoad indexOf = \(imgs.indexOf(myImageView))")

            let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:Selector("imageTapped:"))
            myImageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
            myImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
        }
    }

    func imageTapped(img: UIImageView)
    {

       print("imageTapped  indexOf =  \(imgs.indexOf(img))")

    }

}
```

LOG:

> viewDidLoad indexOf = Optional(0)
>
> viewDidLoad indexOf = Optional(1)
>
> viewDidLoad indexOf = Optional(2)
>
> viewDidLoad indexOf = Optional(3)
>
> viewDidLoad indexOf = Optional(4)
>
> viewDidLoad indexOf = Optional(5)
>
> viewDidLoad indexOf = Optional(6)
>
> viewDidLoad indexOf = Optional(7)
>
> viewDidLoad indexOf = Optional(8)
>
> viewDidLoad indexOf = Optional(9)
>
> viewDidLoad indexOf = Optional(10)
>
> viewDidLoad indexOf = Optional(11)
>
> viewDidLoad indexOf = Optional(12)
>
> viewDidLoad indexOf = Optional(13)
>
> viewDidLoad indexOf = Optional(14)

**Log of tap gesture:**

> imageTapped  indexOf =  nil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `imageTapped` function has the wrong signature; the `action` of a `UIGestureRecognizer` should have one parameter: the gesture recognizer itself. This should work:

```
func imageTapped(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer)
{
    let img = gestureRecognizer.view as! UIImageView
    print("imageTapped  indexOf =  \(imgs.indexOf(img))")
}
```